# If category then echo a custom fields

Tags: custom-field

On a bog standard single.php file how can I echo the following if the post category = "Events" or category ID '4'. The code I'm looking to echo is :

```
        <div class="event-post-icons">
            <ul>
                <li class="single-post-date"><?php the_field('event_date'); ?></li>
                <li class="single-post-time"><?php the_field('event_time'); ?></li>
                <li class="single-post-price"><?php the_field('booking_fee'); ?></li>
                <li class="single-post-palce"><?php the_field('event_location'); ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /event-post-icons -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) function, like this:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 4 ) ) : ?>
    <div class="event-post-icons">
        <ul>
            <li class="single-post-date"><?php the_field('event_date'); ?></li>
            <li class="single-post-time"><?php the_field('event_time'); ?></li>
            <li class="single-post-price"><?php the_field('booking_fee'); ?></li>
            <li class="single-post-palce"><?php the_field('event_location'); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /event-post-icons -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are using this to test a post outside of The Loop, you would need to add the post id:

```
<?php if ( in_category( 4, $post_id ) ) : ?>
```